# RespondToAuthChallengeResult.getAuthenticationResult() return null

Tags: java, amazon-cognito

I try to implement auth through AWS Cognito using [aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity/1.11.152) and for convenience use [cognitoauth classes](https://github.com/kink80/cognitoauth)
Authentication works fine but when I get *AuthenticationResultType* from **respondToAuthChallengeResult** it return *null* why that happens?

Sample:

```
AWSCryptoSettings cryptoParams = new AWSCryptoSettings();
AWSCognitoSession clientSession = new AWSCognitoSession(
            cryptoParams, "test", "123456", USER_POOL_ID);

AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new AnonymousAWSCredentials()))
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();

InitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest()
            .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.USER_SRP_AUTH)
            .withClientId(CLIENT_APP_ID)
            .withAuthParameters(clientSession.step1()); //step1() return Map<String,String> with parameters for auth in it


    //Respond to authentication challenge
    InitiateAuthResult authResult = provider.initiateAuth(authRequest);
    Map<String, String> params = authResult.getChallengeParameters();
    Map<String, String> srpAuthResponses = clientSession.step2(params); //step2() return also Map<String, String> with formatted parameters.

RespondToAuthChallengeRequest respondToAuthChallengeRequest = new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest()
            .withChallengeName(authResult.getChallengeName())
            .withClientId(CLIENT_APP_ID)
            .withChallengeResponses(srpAuthResponses);

RespondToAuthChallengeResult respondToAuthChallengeResult = provider.respondToAuthChallenge(respondToAuthChallengeRequest);

//debug
System.out.println(respondToAuthChallengeResult.getChallengeName());
System.out.println(respondToAuthChallengeResult.getChallengeParameters());
System.out.println(respondToAuthChallengeResult.getAuthenticationResult());

AuthenticationResultType authenticationResultType = respondToAuthChallengeResult.getAuthenticationResult(); //there null is retruned;
```

Output from *sout* is:

> NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED 
>   {userAttributes={"email":"username123@example.com"}, requiredAttributes=[]} 
>   null

I don't configure correctly user pool or something is wrong in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you have created the user through the console or through the [AdminCreateUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) API. The user needs to [create a new password](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-user-accounts.html) as the state says.